# PySCF: Two electron integrals, translate between aosym=s8 and full tensor

Tags: symmetry, pyscf, integrals, fcidump

```
mol = gto.M(atom='O 0 0 0; O 0 0 1; O 0 1 0; O 0 1 1; 
                  O 1 0 0; O 1 0 1; O 1 1 0; O 1 1 1;', basis='6-31G')
sparse_eri = mol.intor('int2e_sph', aosym='s8')
full_eri   = mol.intor('int2e_sph', aosym='a1')
```

For educational purposes, I'd like to understand how I could transform `sparse_eri` into `full_eri`; I'm interested in the general case, that is, something which would work independent of symmetries in the geometry or choice of basis set. **Is there a simple way to relate the two so that I can code it?**

Comment: +1. Welcome to our new community and thank you very much for contributing your question here! We hope to see much more of you! One related question is [this one](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1899/5) in which Tyberius gave an explanation about how to determine which integrals will be equal to 0. In your input file, you have the molecule H2O which [belongs to the C2v symmetry group](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Quantum_Tutorials_(Rioux)/06%3A_Group_Theory_with_Mathcad/6.01%3A_Group_Theory_Principles_Applied_to_H2O).

Comment: Apologies, the example was too simple. I'm interested in the general case, changing the question to clarify.

Comment: All you did was change the geometry and basis set.

Comment: I added the sentence "I'm interested in the general case. "

Comment: I extended to "I'm interested in the general case, that is, something which would work independent of symmetries in the geometry or choice of basis set."

Comment: Would `ao2mo.restore` help? "The function restore() restores a set of integrals to the desired permutation symmetry". The documentation gives some examples: `eri1 = ao2mo.restore(1, numpy.asarray(eri), orb.shape[1])`, `eri4 = ao2mo.restore('4', numpy.asarray(eri), orb.shape[1)`, and `eri8 = ao2mo.restore('s8', numpy.asarray(eri), orb.shape[1])`.